# How to split a column with integer values in csv file to a new columns

Tags: python, csv

I have a one column of numbers, like 22,23,25,32,33,36. and I want to split it new columns in csv file such that first column has 22, second column 23 and so on.

```
import csv
from csv import writer


COLUMNS = 6

with open("Winning No - Sheet1.csv", "r") as input:
    with open("output_file.csv", "w") as f:
        output = writer(f, delimiter=";")
        output.writerow(["Col {}".format(i+1) for i in xrange(COLUMNS)])
        buffer = []
        for row in input:
            buffer.append(row)
            if len(buffer) == COLUMNS:
                output.writerow(row.split(','))
                del buffer[:]
```

When I tried this, I get 6 columns with all the numbers in it such that first column with 22,23,25,32,33,36. Second column with another six numbers. How to sort this out?

Output that I want:

```
COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4 COL5 COL6 
22    23   25   32   33   36
```

Output that I get is actually:

```
COL1        COL2          COL3       COL4     COL5       COL6 
22,23...,36 1,3,,...,36  3,4,...9  4,6,...7  8,9,...10  1,2,....7
```

Comment: Can you actually paste (1) the output you want, and (2) the output you got? Prose descriptions are hard to follow.

Comment: Do you get what i mean?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do something like:

```
output.writerow(row.split(','))
```

I've never used the csv module, but it looks like it also provides a reader which you could use to do the parsing.

Updated with more context:

```
with open("Winning No - Sheet1.csv", "r") as input:
    with open("output_file.csv", "w") as f:
        output = writer(f, delimiter=";")
        output.writerow(["Col {}".format(i+1) for i in xrange(COLUMNS)])
        for row in input:
            output.writerow(row.split(','))
```

Comment: I get an error saying that:                     
output.writerow(input.split(','))
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: @KirthanaGovindarajaoo  sorry, copy/paste error. I've fixed the answer.

Comment: Hey i got it, but the values is not arranged properly. I mean it takes values from 6th row and then 3rd row. How to fix it?

Comment: Perhaps you could add the updated code to your question?

Comment: Total rows in my original file is 1057 rows (One column) but the output that i got is with 6 columns and 177rows, i guess there's missing values too.

Comment: So the original file has one number per line?  And you're trying to put 6 numbers per row of output?

Comment: yes, that's the whole idea of it. each line has 6 numbers separated by commas. I want it to separate into 6 numbers in 6 columns as an output.

Comment: I'm confused.  Is the first line of the input file '22' or '22,23,25,32,33,36'?

Comment: first line of input file is '22,23,25,32,33,36'. I want to separate this line into new 6 columns where first column has 22, second column has 23 and the list goes on.

Comment: @KirthanaGovindarajaoo I updated the answer to show how I mean the split to be used in your code.